# Multiline Chartjs causes issue multiple lines with same data cannot be differentiated

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5-canvas, chartjs-2.6.0

I am displaying a multiline chart using Chartjs.
Many lines here hold same data hence im not able to differentiate them. even if i keep different color for different line i cant see any difference because they all overlap on one another.
At least on hover over the points i want data of all the lines to be shown, but only data on line on the top gets shown. How to understand/see the data in lines behind (first of all how to know which all lines lie behind). (ignore the script error in snippet given below)

```js
var speedCanvas = document.getElementById("speedChart");

Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "Lato";
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 18;

var dataFirst = {
    label: "Car A - Speed (mph)",
    data: [0, 59, 75, 20, 20, 55, 40],
    lineTension: 0,
    fill: false,
    borderColor: 'red'
  };

var dataSecond = {
    label: "Car B - Speed (mph)",
    data: [0, 59, 75, 20, 20, 55, 40],
    lineTension: 0,
    fill: false,
  borderColor: 'blue'
  };

var speedData = {
  labels: ["0s", "10s", "20s", "30s", "40s", "50s", "60s"],
  datasets: [dataFirst, dataSecond]
};

var chartOptions = {
  legend: {
    display: true,
    position: 'top',
    labels: {
      boxWidth: 80,
      fontColor: 'black'
    }
  }
};

var lineChart = new Chart(speedCanvas, {
  type: 'line',
  data: speedData,
  options: chartOptions
});
```

```html
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/sources/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="speedChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

To see all x axes data at once, you can add below configuration in tooltip section

```
mode: 'index'
```

and also you can add configuration so that it looks nice like below

```
intersect: false,
position: 'nearest'
```

in your case, your options would look something like this

```
var chartOptions = {
legend: {
    display: true,
    position: 'top',
    labels: {
       boxWidth: 80,
       fontColor: 'black'
    }
  },
 tooltips:{
        mode: 'index',
        intersect: false,
        position: 'nearest'
 }
};
```

Comment: Can you please share bit of code snippet please im very new to chartjs and usually get confused with configurations

Comment: changed the chart options for your case @Supritha.M.Bhatt

Comment: thank you @Hardik Uchdadiya, but ur code helps be get x-axis details when i hover, but i need details of line that hides behind this(visible red-color) line, because they have same data i want to know all the lines behind the visible line

Comment: @Supritha.M.Bhatt - I think you are looking for this - https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/line/interpolation.html

Comment: thank yo . but no that's not what i was lookin for. thanks for the help